# Better PNG compression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'd like to set the final image to png (for either jpg or png uploaded logos) and also better compress it using the `PNG:` flags as described at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality. How do I use those flags with paperclip? Will it result in good enough compression or is it better to use plugins such as paperclip-optimizer and paperclip-compression?